# Открытие видео fullScreen по нажатию на ссылку?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, подскажите, пожалуйста, есть видео на YouTube, необходимо чтобы при нажатии на гиперссылку на сайте данное видео открывалось в fullScreen с авто воспроизведением, возможно ли такое сделать и как?

Comment: Вряд ли возможно открыть фулскрин, т.к это использовали бы в плохих целях, думаю максимум видео на весь экран, в пределах окна браузера

Answer (score 0):

Можно вставить не на весь экран, но во всё окно, дав ссылку такого типа:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{VIDEO_ID}}?autoplay=1
```

Попробуйте сами: https://www.youtube.com/embed/ALaTm6VzTBw?autoplay=1